# Why does Emojipedia claim that there are 3,521 emojis when I count 2,192?

Tags: unicode

I read this:

> In total there are **3,521 emojis** in the Unicode Standard as of September 2020. This includes sequences for gender or skin tone, flags, and the components that are used to create keycap, flag, and other sequences. The latest emoji release is **Emoji 13.1**.

Source: https://emojipedia.org/stats/

However, on the official list: https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.1/emoji-sequences.txt

There are **1,330** entries, with a total count of **2,192** emojis when you add together the numbers such as `[1]` or `[5]`, which indicate how many emojis are in each entry/range.

What gives? How exactly did Emojipedia come up with the number **3,521**? They do mention that it "includes sequences for gender or skin tone, flags, and the components that are used to create keycap, flag, and other sequences", but those "sequences" seem to be included on the page I linked to. For example, `1F3F4 E0067 E0062 E0065 E006E E0067 E007F` uses multiple code points for a single entry/emoji. It's supposed to be a full, official list of all emojis/ranges.

Is Emojipedia wrong? Does Unicode have some sort of further ability to "combine" characters/emojis which would further increase the number? Is that list not complete after all?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it appears to be about counting emojis and not about running your own website.